# VMC Coin mech tube status via an Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have a vending system with a VMC connected to a coin mech via MDB. 
Also I got an Arduino successfully connected to the same MDB as a cashless device and it is talking to the VMC with no issues.

My question is: How can I get the status of the coin mech coin tubes via this Arduino?

As far as I understand if I need to address the coin mech, my Arduino needs to be the 'master' and as VMC is already present in the system as the 'master' it is not possible unless I remove the VMC from the system and connect my Arduino as the only 'master' to the coin mech.

Could someone please confirm if you have ever tried this scenario?

Comment: What's a VMC? What's an MDB?

Comment: Multi-Drop Bus   , Vendor Machine Controller

Comment: No but this may help https://www.google.com/search?num=50&client=firefox-b&ei=LNn4WsHvK6zMjwSY_I24Dw&q=communication++MDB+vmc+arduino&oq=communication++MDB+vmc+arduino&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5221.6856.0.7240.8.8.0.0.0.0.122.824.4j4.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.600...33i160k1j33i21k1.0.mNzOm6EXOCk

Comment: Can you specify the coin mech used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your feedback.

I think we have only 2 options, either to become the 'master'of the channel or become a slave and just listen to the channel and interpret.

I chosen the second approach. I have accommodated another uC with 2 hardware UARTs to monitor the VMC tx/rx channels to sniff what commands/responses passing through. I've implemented a MDB protocol parser to identify MDB commands from coin mech (ex. POLL command) to get coin tube status when this command issued by the master VMC.

Answer (score 0):

unless you can satisfy your goal by only monitoring the traffic on the bus,
you will have to make the arduino the master, so you will need two ports, one to connect to the multi-drop bust and the other for communication with the VMC

if this MDB is CCTalk that means two serial ports.